# Django - ResolutionError and DistributionError

Tags: python, django

I had to uninstall my django==1.6.4 and install 1.5 for a project, but now when I install 1.6.4 with pip and try to start a project with `django-admin.py startproject PN` I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('Django==1.6.4', 'django-admin.py')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 534, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1432, in run_script
    raise ResolutionError("No script named %r" % script_name)
pkg_resources.ResolutionError: No script named 'django-admin.py'
martinssmacbook:bin martinspasov$ pip install django==1.6.4
```

I tried installing 1.6.5 but then when I try to start a project i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/django-admin.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2876, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 451, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 464, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 639, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Django==1.6.4
```

Any ideas onwhat to do ?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your problem, but : why don't you use virtualenvs ?

Comment: I thought that while i am at beginner level i dont need it, but i guess i was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because you should delete all 1.6.4 files and then install 1.6.5.
but now there are also 1.6.4 files in your Linux / windows.

in windows,

1. you should delete the files in **python/lib/site-packages/django**
   to uninstall the main Django files.
2. nd then delete **Django-VERSION-py2.7.egg** or fix the VERSION in
   it. not just these.
3. you have to delete following 4 files:
   **django-admin.exe**, **django-admin.py**,**django-admin.exe.manifest**,**django-admin-script.py**

then you can reinstall the django.
(In fact, if you know the file, you can try to edit it with change the version.)

in Linux, you can do like that.
if there 's something wrong, you can try to delete all.